# Calling a function to another form, while keeping it a private. vb.net

Tags: vb.net, function

How do I call or use this function from another form, so I can save time?

```
Private Function Working(ByVal move As String, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) As String
    Dim p As Boolean
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.W Then
        Guy.Location = New Point(Guy.Location.X, Guy.Location.Y - 10)
        p = True
    End If
    Return p
End Function
```

Comment: Private means private. If you want to use it from another form make it Public. (Unless you want to cheat and use reflection)

Comment: Your function's return type is a `String`, why are you returning a `Boolean`? Turn `Option Strict On`

Comment: It errors if i dont return a boolean and i know there is a way to do this keeping it private, globals are bad so im trying to avoid them.

Answer (score 0):

The reason 'Private' exists is to prevent other classes from calling a function. You can either make the function `Public` or `Friend` or export it into a new class/module:

```
Module Utils
    Public Function Working(Guy As Guy) As String
        Dim p As Boolean
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.W Then
            Guy.Location = New Point(Guy.Location.X, Guy.Location.Y - 10)
            p = True
        End If

        Return p

    End Function
End Module
```

And call `Utils.Working` from both forms.

Comment: How would i use utils.working on another form when all i get in reply is its not declared.

Comment: Right, you need to add "Public" to the function's definition. I edited my answer

Comment: Turn on Option Strict

Answer (score 0):

as stated above, private is about keeping the subs and functions private. I don't know if this has any sense in this particular case (I doubt a bit), but often it does, when you do something like this:

```
Public Function PublicWorking(ByVal move As String, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) As String
    Dim p as Boolean = Working(move,e)
    Return p
End Function

Private Function Working(ByVal move As String, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) As String
    Dim p As Boolean
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.W Then
        Guy.Location = New Point(Guy.Location.X, Guy.Location.Y - 10)
        p = True
    End If
    Return p
End Function
```

You can call the function "PublicWorking", which will call the Working.

Regards,

Libor